# C macro to return a Struct

Tags: c, struct, macros

Is there a way to have a macro do exactly what this function does? I'm fairly new to C, any help is appreciated!

```
vector vectorScale(float c, vector *v){
    vector result = {v->x * c, v->y * c, v->z * c };
    return result;
}
typedef struct{
    float x,y,z;
}vector;
```

I'm currently trying this but getting errors:

```
#define vectorScale(vector v, vector c)    vector {float (v->x * c); float (v->y * c); float (v->z * c); }
```

Comment: ^this is a macro, you cannot use the function decl. syntax, then `v` isn't defined

Comment: maybe `#define vectorSub(c,v) {(v)->x * (c), (v)->y * (c), (v)->z * (c) }`

Comment: sorry that was a typo, I'll edit it

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That may cause trouble when `c` or `v` expression happens to have side effects.

Comment: An inline function would be superior to a macro.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight couldn't agree more. Hence the warning in my answer

Comment: @bruno okay. It happens. There aren't many other options (besides _not_ creating a macro). I'm thinking about inlining right now :)

Comment: oh, didn't even read this comment. of course !

Comment: I suggest [inlining the function](https://ideone.com/U7OKx9).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
#define vectorScale(c, v) \
    ((vector) {(v)->x * (c), (v)->y * (c), (v)->z * (c) })
```

This construct, of the form `(type) { initial values }`, is called a compound literal. It is an object of the type `type`.

However, with a decent compiler, it should serve to use a static inline function:

```
static inline vector vectorScale(float c, vector *v)
{
    return (vector) {v->x * c, v->y * c, v->z * c };
}
```

A good compiler should optimize this to be as efficient as the macro, and it avoids issues with `v` or `c` being expressions with side effects.

Answer (score 5):

macros arguments don't have a type. You want:

```
#define vectorSub(c,v) {(v)->x * (c), (v)->y * (c), (v)->z * (c) }
```

That's the best equivalent unless someone calls your macro like this:

```
vector v2 = vectorSub(i++,v);
```

which is the common issue with macros using their parameters more than once because it will expand as:

```
{(v)->x * (i++), (v)->y * (i++), (v)->z * (i++) }
```

Complete self-contained and compiling example:

```
typedef struct  {
  float x,y,z;
} vector;

#define vectorSub(c,v) {(v)->x * (c), (v)->y * (c), (v)->z * (c) } 

vector foo()
{
  vector v = {0,3,4};
  vector v2 = vectorSub(12,&v);
  return v2;
}
```

note that a good compiler can/will inline such short functions, as your original `vectorScale`, specially if the `inline` keyword is used to send a hint the compiler (compiler doesn't necessarily comply) and the function is in the header file, so macros aren't the best choice here, specially since they don't involve macro trickery like token-pasting or stringing.

Comment: I understand it is best practice to use inlines, when I use static inline and try compiling it I get the following error:

cc -xinline=%vectorScale q1/test.c -o bin/test
cc: error: language inline=%vectorScale not recognized

Comment: that's a completely different issue with your exotic/old compiler and its command line options.

Comment: @AbhishekRavi do you understand the danger with the macro in case at least a parameter contains side effect ?

Comment: I do see the dangers, this is for understanding purposes mainly, not going to any important use cases.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!